# Why are the divs not affected by css?

Tags: html, css

The css only affects the first box. It does not make any sense. margin-bottom will only separate the first row from the second row and then it does not work. How do I fix this.
Here is a link to the test site. http://stack.x10.mx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that both of the divs inside each `srow` div are floated, which means that the DOM doesn't count their height, and your `srow` divs essentially end up with a height of 0px. That's why you've had to set a bottom margin of 160px but only get a gap of 10px or so - your margin covers the entire height of the two items in each row, and then anything left over appears as the spacing. The second row's content is taller than 160px, so nothing is left over to appear as a gap.

The core problem is a slightly poorly coded layout, but if you wanted a quick (albeit slightly hacky) solution to this problem, just add `<br style="clear:both;" />` inside each row, after the two content divs. This forces the DOM to recognise their height, which means your `srow` divs now have the correct height. Then, you can change the bottom margin of the row to something sensible like 10px, knowing that the layout will be calculated correctly.

Comment: If someone can point out why this was down-voted, I'd be happy to update (or remove) my answer accordingly.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it might be because the of the quality of the question: It's going to be closed because there's no self-contained sample code. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255853/should-downvotes-be-used-to-punish-people-who-answer-bad-questions. 
Note that if a question is deleted, you will lose any rep from the answer; so these types of questions can often not be worth your time.

Comment: It was a poor question, and it quite possibly will be deleted, but the loss of rep doesn't bother me really. I use to site to help people, which is a lot more fun than trying to increase a number :p I think I helped this asker; that's good enough for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Why is all the css inline? In a CSS file, or the  element in the head, add:

```
.sdw{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```